# Which of tables key to reference?

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-key, primary-key

MySQL.

There is a table `users` with autoincrement primary key `id`.

There is also a table `employees` (every employee is a user but not vice versa). The `employees` primary key is `userid`. The field `userid` is not autoincrement.

`employees.userid` is a foreign key for `users.id`.

Thus every employee's primary key value is also `users` primary key value.

Now consider a third table rows of which should refer to an employee.

The question: Should the third table refer to `users.id` or to `employees.userid`?

Comment: You say *"Now consider a third table rows of which should refer to an **employee.**"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the third table is related to employees and not to every user, you should reference employees.userid.

It makes sense for, say, a table of employee identity card numbers to reference "employees"."userid". But it makes sense for a table of email addresses to reference "users"."userid", because *every* user has an email address.